# Run JS Functions run in sequence onclick

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have been trying to get these functions to run in sequence using onclick for the first and ID for the second. What I am trying to do is have the the "loading" script run and then show the "result" after the "loading" timeout. Thanks in advance for the help.

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="btn_copy" onclick="show()" />
</span><label>Result:</label>
<span type="text" id="result_paste"><img id="loading" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none"></span>
<input type="text" id="result_copy">
```

JS:

```
function show() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout("hide()", 1000);
}

function hide() {
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}

$(function result() {
    $('#btn_copy').on('click', function () {
        var get_val = $('#result_copy').val();
        if (!get_val) {
            alert("Please Enter Some Value");
            return false;
        }
        $('#result_paste').text(get_val);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you have 2 click listeners on your button - one in html, another in JS. That's not usually a good idea, so let's remove html one.

Than, as it was pointed out, you need to pass function, not a string, to `setTimeout`: `setTimeout(hide, 1000)`

And finally, the logic on click should be:

1. Hide result container and show loading image.
2. Plan hiding the image and showing the container in 1 second.
3. Actually put the value into the container.

Here is a snippet:

```js
function showLoading() {
    document.getElementById("result_paste").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
}

function showResult() {
    document.getElementById("result_paste").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}

$(function init() {
    $('#btn_copy').on('click', function () {
        var get_val = $('#result_copy').val();
        if (!get_val) {
            alert("Please Enter Some Value");
            return false;
        }
        
        showLoading();
        setTimeout(showResult, 1000);
        $('#result_paste').text(get_val);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="result_copy">
<input type="button" id="btn_copy" value="OK" />
<br/>
<label>Result:</label>
<div type="text" id="result_paste"></div>
<img id="loading" src="ajax-loader.gif" alt="loading" style="display: none">
```

(or here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aofj25bv/3/)

Comment: Thanks Treble that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Change `setTimeout("hide()", 1000)` to `setTimeout(hide, 1000)`

Comment: I tried this code but result script overrides the loading script. I am trying to show the loading for a set time frame then the result

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show() {
  console.log('show')
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "block";
  setTimeout(() => hide(), 1000);
}

function hide() {
  console.log('hide')
  document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<input type="button" id="btn_copy" onclick="show()" value="button">
</span><label>Result:</label>
<span type="text" id="result_paste"><img id="loading" src="ajax-loader.gif" style="display: none"></span>
```

Comment: I tried this code but result script overrides the loading script. I am trying to show the loading for a set time frame then the result

Comment: It's not the final code. This code is just to show how to use `setTimeout` properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch

```
setInterval("hide()", 1000);
```

By

```
setInterval(hide(), 1000);
```

Comment: I tried this code but result script overrides the loading script. I am trying to show the loading for a set time frame then the result